# iphone background images when changing device rotation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, interface-builder, uiimageview

I have an `UIImageView` as a background behind my controls, the problem comes when rotating the device. I'd like to use a different `image` depending on the `orientation`.

So what would be the best way to handle that?
Adding and removing each `UIImageView` for landscape and portrait?
Having both on the view and hide/show the appropriate one?
Or maybe there is some class or `UIObject` for handling that?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get funky with it and have both background images overlaid, one with alpha = 1.0 and the other with alpha = 0.0. Then, when you rotation, use an animation to transition the alphas to 0.0 and 1.0, respectively to get a fade-in fade-out effect. If you choose this approach, I recommend putting the animation code in `-viewWillAppear:` For example, something like this:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL]; {
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
        [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
        if (toOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscape) {
                landscapeView.alpha = 1.0;
                portraitView.alpha = 0.0;
        }
        else {
                landscapeView.alpha = 0.0;
                portraitView.alpha = 1.0;
        }
} [UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: don't put it in the view hierarchy if it's not being used. if a user never changes the orientation (likely use case), you are wasting memory.

Comment: you can always add it to the hierarchy the first time a rotation occurs, or even remove it once the animation is complete.

Comment: Maybe I could just remove the image from the hierarchy when the fade out is finished, and add it before starting to fade in.

Comment: @Pier: Yes, that's a good idea. You can easily add this functionality with the method `[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(removeImage)];`

Comment: In AS3 I use a tween engine called TweenLite that has already implemented this. I suppose there's nothing like that in objective-c ios? :)

Comment: @Pier: Nothing that I've come across.

Answer (score 1):

You can just set its image property to a different image.

```
someUIImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"foo.png"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Now you can actually use size classes for this purpose. All you need to do is to set images for Any width compact height and do the hint given in this article: http://pinkstone.co.uk/how-to-handle-device-rotation-since-ios-8/
That's all you need for your background image to change on rotation.